# Oracle Procedure unpivot data into destination using data splitting logic used in existing procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, unpivot

I have a PL/SQL procedure which takes string at runtime which is comma separated,splits it and pushes into table.
Example of procedure and table is given here:
Procedure is push_data.
Current table where data is getting inserted is push_data_temp.

Now as per requirement, i need to write a new procedure where logic would remain same of splitting data, but in the new table push_data_pivot(structure inside pivot), should display data pivoted in this format.

Ex: if currently data in push_data_temp is:
[image]

The data should go in push_data_pivot in the new procedure as:
[image]

The logic should remain same, just that the data getting inserted would go into columns instead of rows, populating id and value columns.

Here column **id**, is the unique identifier for the string passed in both tables. Basically, it is same as the one used in original table.

Was unable to update fiddle for push_data_pivot structure so mentioning the latest structure and data here:
PUSH_DATA_PIVOT :

```
create table PUSH_DATA_PIVOT
(
id_pk NUMBER,
  id NUMBER,
  label_id number,
  label varchar2(4000),
  value varchar2(4000)
);

insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL01',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL02',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL03',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL04',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL05',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL06',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL07',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL08',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL09',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL10',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL11',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL12',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL13',null);
insert into push_data_pivot values(1,null,'COL14',null);
```

The sample data is single string, for single label_id and corresponding set of column label values.However actual table would have multiple such strings inserted on basis of id column, same as original requirement. This is already handled in existing procedure using cursor.

**The only requirement is, to create new procedure with new destination table as push_data_pivot and data in unpivoted format. Split logic would be same as in existing procedure.**

Comment: So what do you want to happen if there is more than one row in PUSH_DATA_TEMP table? Presumably the number of rows in this is data is not fixed? You want a procedure which can handle one row or many rows. Do you expect a maximum number of rows?

Comment: The existing is already handling it with cursor, so rows for multiple ids will get inserted. Similar is expected in the new table, just that the data would be unpivoted.

Comment: Also, the destination table now is push data_pivot. I gave reference of existing procedure  because the logic to split the string passed as input at runtime would be same.

Comment: So just as string was pushing data in push_data_temp in columns, as cited in screenshots and also in fiddle. I wish to write similar procedure, with similar split logic, just that destination table is now push_data_pivot and in the format shown in screenshot.

Comment: So, data was earlier split in columns, now same would be split in rows.

Comment: You've edited this question several times without clarifying the bits which really need clarifications. Please explain more about your expected input data. Will you always have COL01 through COL14, or will the initial strings have varying numbers of tokens? Also, provide expected output for (equivalent of) two rows in PUSH_DATA_TEMP.

Comment: COL01 to COL14 are the labels and these will be fixed. I have added 2 outputs for push_data_temp in the fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fae31c11a4ad6205ebcaa418a0bffffd

Comment: I edited because i assumed it needed further clarity in requirement. Also initially fiddle was not getting updated with push_data_pivot table and data info, so i added that to question also for reference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the answer to this question.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=412a6e27a22741ee1c31eee4a3f2bf3

Answer (score 2):

If the list of columns in PUSH_DATA_TEMP is fixed, then a standard UNPIVOT will all thats needed, eg

```
SQL> create table push_data_temp
  2   ( id  int,
  3     col1 varchar2(20),
  4     col2 varchar2(20),
  5     col3 varchar2(20),
  6     col4 varchar2(20),
  7     col5 varchar2(20),
  8     col6 varchar2(20),
  9     col7 varchar2(20),
 10     col8 varchar2(20),
 11     col9 varchar2(20),
 12     col10 varchar2(20),
 13     col11 varchar2(20),
 14     col12 varchar2(20),
 15     col13 varchar2(20),
 16     col14 varchar2(20)
 17  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into push_data_temp values
  2   (1,'c1data','c2data','c3data','c4data','c5data','c6data','c7data',
  3      'c8data','c9data','c10data','c11data','c12data','c13data','c14data' );

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into push_data_temp values
  2   (2,'c1dataX','c2dataX','c3dataX','c4dataX','c5dataX','c6dataX','c7dataX',
  3      'c8dataX','c9dataX','c10dataX','c11dataX','c12dataX','c13dataX','c14dataX' );

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Unpivot ...

```
SQL> select *
  2  from   push_data_temp
  3  unpivot (value for label
  4    IN (col1 AS 'COL-1', col2 AS 'COL-2',col3 AS 'COL-3',col4 AS 'COL-4',col5 AS 'COL-5',col6 AS 'COL-6',col7 AS 'COL-7',
  5        col8 AS 'COL-8',col9 AS 'COL-9',col10 AS 'COL-10',col11 AS 'COL-11',col12 AS 'COL-12',col13 AS 'COL-13',col14 AS 'COL-14'
  6    ));

        ID LABEL  VALUE
---------- ------ --------------------
         1 COL-1  c1data
         1 COL-2  c2data
         1 COL-3  c3data
         1 COL-4  c4data
         1 COL-5  c5data
         1 COL-6  c6data
         1 COL-7  c7data
         1 COL-8  c8data
         1 COL-9  c9data
         1 COL-10 c10data
         1 COL-11 c11data
         1 COL-12 c12data
         1 COL-13 c13data
         1 COL-14 c14data
         2 COL-1  c1dataX
         2 COL-2  c2dataX
         2 COL-3  c3dataX
         2 COL-4  c4dataX
         2 COL-5  c5dataX
         2 COL-6  c6dataX
         2 COL-7  c7dataX
         2 COL-8  c8dataX
         2 COL-9  c9dataX
         2 COL-10 c10dataX
         2 COL-11 c11dataX
         2 COL-12 c12dataX
         2 COL-13 c13dataX
         2 COL-14 c14dataX

28 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: I need to write a separate procedure for this and cannot use push_data_temp. I gave its reference for the data split logic. I need to write new proc, with destination as push_data_pivot which would take string as input, split it as per regex logic given, and then push into push_data_pivot table if records exists else update. I also cannot use merge for insert/Update as oracle 12.1 doesn't support merge inside proc and cannot upgrade to higher versions.

Comment: I'm lost - if you have existing logic that can split the string into a structure with keys plus 14 columns, then that structure could easily a nested table type, or a global temporary table, and the unpivot SQL will work on that.

Also, MERGE works fine in a proc, you just need to use dynamic SQL not static SQL if necessary

Comment: You are right but because i am inexperienced in pl/sql i need help with it. We can split and use nested table and unpivot. But need help with it. Also merge isn't working for oracle 12.1 It will work 12.2 onwards